# Best structure for MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key

I'm designing my table, but I have doubts: I will have two columns `A` and `B` that cannot have repetitions and, in the same row, can't both be `null`.

I don't know if the best thing to do is to use a primary key with a combination of the values of `A` and `B` or a completely different column (for example an autoincremented column).

Comment: If you can give more information about what those two columns represent it will help with answers.

Comment: For example VAT identification number and another code similar to the social security number. The user can submit the first, the second or both, but cannot leave both blank

Comment: Could you put that into the question? Also might help to give a sample row or two of what you are thinking

Comment: *two columns A and B that cannot have repetitions* Separately or together?

Comment: Thanks to all of you, but the answer that I was searching is the one that @RickJames wrote. Sorry if I was not clear I'm writing my question, next time I will do better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `PRIMARY KEY` does not allow `NULLs`.  But a `UNIQUE KEY` does.  I suggest you try a simple table that has `A` and `B`, each nullable, then `INSERT` suitable combinations to see if they work.

`UNIQUE(A,B)` says that the *pair* is unique, while allowing either column to be repeated.  Your Question is vague--is that what you wanted?

This will not check for "can't both be null"; that would have to be tested for at the application level.

Based on your Comment, you seem to be asking about the `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT`, not the table definition.  And it seems like neither column should allow `NULLs`:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    vat ... NOT NULL,
    ssn ... NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(vat),
    UNIQUE(ssn)
)
```

(or swap the two keys)

Then the *application* should decide which of these to use:

```
SELECT ... WHERE vat = ?
SELECT ... WHERE ssn = ?
SELECT ... WHERE vat = ? AND ssn = ?
```

depending on what is given in the `<form>`.

Comment: Thanks, you have been clear enough to make me understand ;)